# Storing key-value pairs with or without a hash in redis

Tags: python, performance, hash, redis, key-value-store

I am storing key-value pairs in a Redis database via the [Redis-py](https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py) client. All keys are unique, there are no duplicates. Here's an example :

```
key = 133735570
value = {"key":133735570,"value":[[141565041,1.2],[22592300,1.0],[162439394,1.0],[19397942,1.0],[79996146,1.0],[84352985,1.0],[123276403,1.0],[18356816,1.0],[113839687,1.0],[16235789,1.0],[144779115,1.0],[94628304,1.0],[134973120,1.0],[138501363,1.0],[34351681,1.0],[80202522,1.0],[81561595,1.0],[18913677,1.0],[130488590,1.0],[128208311,1.0],[93912155,0.5]]}
```

Would adding a hash (same as the key name) improve performance? For example,

```
key = 133735570
hash = 133735570
value = {"key":133735570,"value":[[141565041,1.2],[22592300,1.0],[162439394,1.0],[19397942,1.0],[79996146,1.0],[84352985,1.0],[123276403,1.0],[18356816,1.0],[113839687,1.0],[16235789,1.0],[144779115,1.0],[94628304,1.0],[134973120,1.0],[138501363,1.0],[34351681,1.0],[80202522,1.0],[81561595,1.0],[18913677,1.0],[130488590,1.0],[128208311,1.0],[93912155,0.5]]}
```

My requirement is to look-up keys so as to retrieve the corresponding values from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to store your key-value pairs (value part in your example) within [hash](http://redis.io/commands#hash) data structure (where key part of your pair would be stored as hash field and value part as hash value; check out [HMSET](http://redis.io/commands/hmset)) which is more flexible for data manipulation and might [consume less memory](http://nosql.mypopescu.com/post/1010844204/redis-memory-usage) than plain value strings.

Comment: So, I should do redisObject.hmset(key,value) instead of the current redisObject.hset(key,key,value) ? Note : there are *NO* duplicate keys. Would it still help being memory efficient?

Comment: Oh, so you are already using hashes? HMSET allows you to set multiple field/value pairs in one operation to the hash. According to the article it should be memory efficient but there is only one way to be sure, so you'll have to probably try it out.